# mailcore2- A stable connection to the server could not be established

Tags: outlook, smtp, mailcore2

I'm using Mailcore2 for sending mails. It works when configured with gmail account settings. However, it gives the above error when configured with outlook smtp settings.."A stable connection to the server could not be established."

The SMTP settings for Outlook.

```
MCOSMTPSession *smtpSession = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
smtpSession.hostname = smtp.office365.com"; // also tried smtp.outlook.office365.com
smtpSession.port = 587; // also tried 25 
smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS;
smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2;// tried MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2Outlook;  
smtpSession.timeout = 30.0;
```

Below are the connection logger logs

```
220 BM1PR01CA0097.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 19 Jun 2018 10:31:08 +0000
EHLO silicus-lt-87.silicus.com
250-BM1PR01CA0097.outlook.office365.com Hello [59.160.69.66]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
STARTTLS
(null)
250-BM1PR01CA0097.outlook.office365.com Hello [59.160.69.66]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

> 2018-06-19 16:01:13.586179+0530 Error sending email: Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=A stable connection to the server could not be established.}

Is there something additional that needs to be configured?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. The 'From' address being used while sending the mail was a non-outlook email account. After changing it to a valid outlook account, it worked as expected.